# MySQL - Pairing Data within table taking gaps and missing data into account

Tags: mysql, join

The following subsets of data I show below is a fraction for which I have to find a solution in terms of pairing the RecOn with RecOFF, or allow for a null / empty record to appear for either RecON or RecOFF.
The possible sets of combinations within the dataset are possible and I present the solution to this as well. Below that is an export of example data and then my solution that I've created so far to it, which does not suffice in all the examples.

In the long run I would like to create an easier function for this, as the data has to be normalised from the raw data, I cannot use any other language than MySQL for this, unless it would really not be possible.

**Theoretical options**

```
Rec ON/OFF | RecordTime
RecON      | 8:00:00
RecOFF     | 9:00:00
RecOFF     | 10:00:00
RecON      | 11:00:00
RecOFF     | 12:00:00
RecON      | 14:00:00
RecON      | 15:00:00
```

**This should go into**

```
TimeRecON | TimeRecOFF
8:00      | 9:00
null      | 10:00
11:00     | 12:00
14:00     | null
15:00     | null
```

**Sample data:**

```
INSERT INTO `tbltest` (`id`,`GroupName`,`Observer`,`ArrivalTime`,`Behaviour`,`RecordTime`) VALUES (4865,'Make-e-plan','BANK','2017-08-26 16:23:47','RecON','16:23:53');
INSERT INTO `tbltest` (`id`,`GroupName`,`Observer`,`ArrivalTime`,`Behaviour`,`RecordTime`) VALUES (4878,'Make-e-plan','BANK','2017-08-26 16:23:47','RecOFF','17:33:24');
INSERT INTO `tbltest` (`id`,`GroupName`,`Observer`,`ArrivalTime`,`Behaviour`,`RecordTime`) VALUES (4890,'Make-e-plan','BANK','2017-08-26 16:23:47','RecOFF','18:50:07');
INSERT INTO `tblTest` (`id`,`GroupName`,`Observer`,`ArrivalTime`,`Behaviour`,`RecordTime`) VALUES (352,'Baobab','DILA','2017-08-16 07:55:52','RecON','08:58:45');
INSERT INTO `tblTest` (`id`,`GroupName`,`Observer`,`ArrivalTime`,`Behaviour`,`RecordTime`) VALUES (377,'Baobab','DILA','2017-08-16 07:55:52','RecOFF','10:50:42');
INSERT INTO `tblTest` (`id`,`GroupName`,`Observer`,`ArrivalTime`,`Behaviour`,`RecordTime`) VALUES (379,'Baobab','DILA','2017-08-16 07:55:52','RecOFF','10:51:13');
INSERT INTO `tblTest` (`id`,`GroupName`,`Observer`,`ArrivalTime`,`Behaviour`,`RecordTime`) VALUES (382,'Baobab','DILA','2017-08-16 07:55:52','RecOFF','10:56:36');
INSERT INTO `tblTest` (`id`,`GroupName`,`Observer`,`ArrivalTime`,`Behaviour`,`RecordTime`) VALUES (384,'Baobab','DILA','2017-08-16 07:55:52','RecON','10:59:58');
INSERT INTO `tblTest` (`id`,`GroupName`,`Observer`,`ArrivalTime`,`Behaviour`,`RecordTime`) VALUES (396,'Baobab','DILA','2017-08-16 07:55:52','RecON','11:20:45');
INSERT INTO `tblTest` (`id`,`GroupName`,`Observer`,`ArrivalTime`,`Behaviour`,`RecordTime`) VALUES (412,'Baobab','DILA','2017-08-16 07:55:52','RecOFF','12:04:04');
```

**My Query So far**

```
SELECT `id`, `GroupName`, `Observer`, `ArrivalTime`, `Behaviour`,   `RecOnTime`, `RecOffTime`, `PreviousContext`, `PreviousBehaviour`, `PreviousID`
FROM (
    SELECT `id`, `GroupName`, `Observer`, `ArrivalTime`, `Behaviour`, `RecordTime` `RecOfftime`, -- note that the recordtime is RecOFF here 
     @lastContext `PreviousContext`, 
    @lastBehaviour `PreviousBehaviour`, @lastid `PreviousID`,
        CASE 
            WHEN @lastBehaviour <> `Behaviour`                                   -- The previous record has to be RecON (this statement could be re-written to = "RecON")
                AND `Behaviour` = "RecOFF"
            THEN @lastRecordTime
            ELSE 
            CASE WHEN @lastBehaviour = 'RecON' AND `Behaviour`= 'RecON'             -- IF there are two RecON instances after each other without a RecOFF then put the previous instance as first RecON
            THEN @lastRecordTime
            ELSE "00:00:00"                                                         -- IF RecOn and RecOFF do not match enter 0
            END
        END                
        AS `RecOnTime`,
        @lastid := `id`,
        @lastRecordTime := TIME(`RecordTime`),
        @lastBehaviour := `Behaviour`,

    FROM `KMP_adlib_testing`.`tblAdlibRaw`
    WHERE `Behaviour` IN ('RecOn', 'RecOFF')                                        -- This pre-filters for only RecON and RecOFF behaviours
        AND `Observer` = @varObserver AND `GroupName` = @varGroupName AND ArrivalTime = @varArrivalTime
    ) as `tmp`
     WHERE  RecOnTime <> "00:00:00"                                                -- This filters all records where there is no RecON for the behaviours.. This could be re-entered as where the Context is null????
;
```

**My Expected solution to the Example data provided would be:**

```
Group       | Observer | RecON    | RecOFF
Baobab      | DILA     | 08:58:45 | 10:50:42
Baobab      | DILA     | null     | 10:51:13
Baobab      | DILA     | null     | 10:56:36
Baobab      | DILA     | 10:59:58 | null     
Baobab      | DILA     | 11:20:45 | 12:04:04
Make-e-plan | BANK     | 16:23:53 | 17:33:24
Make-e-plan | BANK     | null     | 18:50:07
```

**A working version of the query based on Used_By_Already's response.**
I feel still can be optimised.

```
select   groupname
, observer
    , ArrivalTime
    , TimeOn
    , case INNER2.rownum_difference WHEN 1 THEN INNER2.TimeOff ELSE NULL END   AS TIMEOFF
FROM (
  SELECT
            groupname
          , observer
          , ArrivalTime
          , t1.RecordTime TimeOn
          , (SELECT
                    MIN(t2.RecordTime)
                  FROM tblAdlibPreProcessing t2
                  WHERE t2.GroupName = t1.GroupName
                  AND t2.Observer = t1.Observer
                  AND t2.Behaviour = 'RecOFF'
                  AND t2.RecordTime > t1.RecordTime
                  AND t2.GroupName = @groupname
                  AND t2.Observer = @observer
                  AND t2.ArrivalTime = @arrivaltime
            )      
            TimeOff
 -- This can remain out               
 --             , (SELECT id
 --                     FROM tbltest t3
 --                     WHERE  t3.RecordTime = (SELECT  MIN(t2.RecordTime)
 --                          FROM tblAdlibPreProcessing t2
 --                                              WHERE t2.GroupName = t1.GroupName
 --                                              AND t2.Observer = t1.Observer
 --                                              AND t2.Behaviour = 'RecOFF'
 --                                              AND t2.RecordTime > t1.RecordTime
 --                                              AND t2.GroupName = @groupname
 --                                              AND t2.Observer = @observer
 --                                              AND t2.ArrivalTime = @arrivaltime
 --                                              )
 --               ) rownum_time_off
 --               , t1.id as rownum_time_on
 -- End this can be left out
              , (SELECT id
                  FROM tblAdlibPreProcessing t3
                  WHERE 1=1
                  AND t3.GroupName = @groupname
        AND t3.Observer = @observer
                  AND t3.ArrivalTime = @arrivaltime
                  AND  t3.RecordTime = (SELECT  MIN(t2.RecordTime)
                      FROM tblAdlibPreProcessing t2
                                          WHERE t2.GroupName = t1.GroupName
                                          AND t2.Observer = t1.Observer
                                          AND t2.Behaviour = 'RecOFF'
                                          AND t2.RecordTime > t1.RecordTime
                                          AND t2.GroupName = @groupname
                                          AND t2.Observer = @observer
                                          AND t2.ArrivalTime = @arrivaltime
                                          )
            ) -  t1.id as rownum_difference
    FROM tblAdlibPreProcessing t1
    WHERE Behaviour = 'RecON'
    AND t1.GroupName = @groupname
    AND t1.Observer = @observer
    AND t1.ArrivalTime = @arrivaltime
) INNER2        
UNION ALL
SELECT
    ou.groupname
  , ou.observer
  , ou.ArrivalTime
  , NULL
  , ou.RecordTime
FROM ( 
    -- off_unpaired
    SELECT
            groupname
          , observer
          , ArrivalTime
          , t1.RecordTime
          , (SELECT
                    MAX(t2.RecordTime)
            FROM tblAdlibPreProcessing t2
            WHERE t2.GroupName = t1.GroupName
            AND t2.Observer = t1.Observer
            AND t2.Behaviour = 'RecON'
            AND t2.RecordTime < t1.RecordTime)
            max_t2_rt
    FROM tblAdlibPreProcessing t1
    WHERE Behaviour = 'RecOFF'
    AND t1.GroupName = @groupname
  AND t1.Observer = @observer
AND t1.ArrivalTime = @arrivaltime
 ) ou
LEFT JOIN ( 
    -- on_off_paired
    SELECT
            groupname
          , observer
          , ArrivalTime
          , t1.RecordTime TimeOn
          , (SELECT
                    MIN(t2.RecordTime)
            FROM tblAdlibPreProcessing t2
            WHERE t2.GroupName = t1.GroupName
            AND t2.Observer = t1.Observer
            AND t2.Behaviour = 'RecOFF'
            AND t2.RecordTime > t1.RecordTime
            AND t2.GroupName = @groupname
            AND t2.Observer = @observer
            AND t2.ArrivalTime = @arrivaltime)
            TimeOff
    FROM tblAdlibPreProcessing t1
    WHERE Behaviour = 'RecON'
 ) oop ON ou.groupname = oop.groupname
    AND ou.observer = oop.observer
    AND ou.ArrivalTime = oop.ArrivalTime
    AND ou.max_t2_rt = oop.TimeOn
    AND ou.RecordTime = oop.TimeOff
WHERE oop.groupname IS NULL
ORDER BY  1, 2, 3, 4, 5;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a different answer now that the expected results are available. I think this is much closer.  I believe it can be refined much like I did the earlier version, but have (for now) run out of time to add that.

In this solution approach I am using `WITH` (common table expression) so there is also a second variant for MySQL versions prior to support of `WITH`:

> ```
> create table `tbltest` (`id` int,`GroupName` varchar(40),`Observer` varchar(40),`ArrivalTime` time,`Behaviour` varchar(20),`RecordTime` time);
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO `tbltest` (`id`,`GroupName`,`Observer`,`ArrivalTime`,`Behaviour`,`RecordTime`)
> VALUES
>    (4865,'Make-e-plan','BANK','2017-08-26 16:23:47','RecON','16:23:53')
>  , (4878,'Make-e-plan','BANK','2017-08-26 16:23:47','RecOFF','17:33:24')
>  , (4890,'Make-e-plan','BANK','2017-08-26 16:23:47','RecOFF','18:50:07')
>  , (352,'Baobab','DILA','2017-08-16 07:55:52','RecON','08:58:45')
>  , (377,'Baobab','DILA','2017-08-16 07:55:52','RecOFF','10:50:42')
>  , (379,'Baobab','DILA','2017-08-16 07:55:52','RecOFF','10:51:13')
>  , (382,'Baobab','DILA','2017-08-16 07:55:52','RecOFF','10:56:36')
>  , (384,'Baobab','DILA','2017-08-16 07:55:52','RecON','10:59:58')
>  , (396,'Baobab','DILA','2017-08-16 07:55:52','RecON','11:20:45')
>  , (412,'Baobab','DILA','2017-08-16 07:55:52','RecOFF','12:04:04');
> ```

**Using `with`**

> ```
> WITH on_off_paired AS (
>         SELECT
>                 groupname
>               , observer
>               , ArrivalTime
>               , t1.RecordTime TimeOn
>               , (SELECT
>                         MIN(t2.RecordTime)
>                 FROM tbltest t2
>                 WHERE t2.GroupName = t1.GroupName
>                 AND t2.Observer = t1.Observer
>                 AND t2.Behaviour = 'RecOFF'
>                 AND t2.RecordTime > t1.RecordTime)
>                 TimeOff
>         FROM tbltest t1
>         WHERE Behaviour = 'RecON'
>         )
> , off_unpaired AS (
>         SELECT
>                 groupname
>               , observer
>               , ArrivalTime
>               , t1.RecordTime
>               , (SELECT
>                         MAX(t2.RecordTime)
>                 FROM tbltest t2
>                 WHERE t2.GroupName = t1.GroupName
>                 AND t2.Observer = t1.Observer
>                 AND t2.Behaviour = 'RecON'
>                 AND t2.RecordTime < t1.RecordTime)
>                 max_t2_rt
>         FROM tbltest t1
>         WHERE Behaviour = 'RecOFF'
>         )
> SELECT
>         groupname
>       , observer
>       , ArrivalTime
>       , TimeOn
>       , TimeOff
> FROM on_off_paired
> UNION ALL
> SELECT
>         ou.groupname
>       , ou.observer
>       , ou.ArrivalTime
>       , NULL
>       , ou.RecordTime
> FROM off_unpaired ou
> LEFT JOIN on_off_paired oop ON ou.groupname = oop.groupname
>         AND ou.observer = oop.observer
>         AND ou.ArrivalTime = oop.ArrivalTime
>         AND ou.max_t2_rt = oop.TimeOn
>         AND ou.RecordTime = oop.TimeOff
> WHERE oop.groupname IS NULL
> ORDER BY 1, 2, 3, 5;
> ```
>
> ```
> groupname   | observer | ArrivalTime | TimeOn   | TimeOff 
> :---------- | :------- | :---------- | :------- | :-------
> Baobab      | DILA     | 07:55:52    | 08:58:45 | 10:50:42
> Baobab      | DILA     | 07:55:52    | null     | 10:51:13
> Baobab      | DILA     | 07:55:52    | null     | 10:56:36
> Baobab      | DILA     | 07:55:52    | 11:20:45 | 12:04:04
> Baobab      | DILA     | 07:55:52    | 10:59:58 | 12:04:04
> Make-e-plan | BANK     | 16:23:47    | 16:23:53 | 17:33:24
> Make-e-plan | BANK     | 16:23:47    | null     | 18:50:07
> ```

**Without `with`**

> ```
> -- where WITH is unavailable
> SELECT
>         groupname
>       , observer
>       , ArrivalTime
>       , TimeOn
>       , TimeOff
> FROM (  
>         -- on_off_paired
>         SELECT
>                 groupname
>               , observer
>               , ArrivalTime
>               , t1.RecordTime TimeOn
>               , (SELECT
>                         MIN(t2.RecordTime)
>                 FROM tbltest t2
>                 WHERE t2.GroupName = t1.GroupName
>                 AND t2.Observer = t1.Observer
>                 AND t2.Behaviour = 'RecOFF'
>                 AND t2.RecordTime > t1.RecordTime)
>                 TimeOff
>         FROM tbltest t1
>         WHERE Behaviour = 'RecON'
>      ) D1
> UNION ALL
> SELECT
>         ou.groupname
>       , ou.observer
>       , ou.ArrivalTime
>       , NULL
>       , ou.RecordTime
> FROM ( 
>         -- off_unpaired
>         SELECT
>                 groupname
>               , observer
>               , ArrivalTime
>               , t1.RecordTime
>               , (SELECT
>                         MAX(t2.RecordTime)
>                 FROM tbltest t2
>                 WHERE t2.GroupName = t1.GroupName
>                 AND t2.Observer = t1.Observer
>                 AND t2.Behaviour = 'RecON'
>                 AND t2.RecordTime < t1.RecordTime)
>                 max_t2_rt
>         FROM tbltest t1
>         WHERE Behaviour = 'RecOFF'
>      ) ou
> LEFT JOIN ( 
>         -- on_off_paired
>         SELECT
>                 groupname
>               , observer
>               , ArrivalTime
>               , t1.RecordTime TimeOn
>               , (SELECT
>                         MIN(t2.RecordTime)
>                 FROM tbltest t2
>                 WHERE t2.GroupName = t1.GroupName
>                 AND t2.Observer = t1.Observer
>                 AND t2.Behaviour = 'RecOFF'
>                 AND t2.RecordTime > t1.RecordTime)
>                 TimeOff
>         FROM tbltest t1
>         WHERE Behaviour = 'RecON'
>   ) oop ON ou.groupname = oop.groupname
>         AND ou.observer = oop.observer
>         AND ou.ArrivalTime = oop.ArrivalTime
>         AND ou.max_t2_rt = oop.TimeOn
>         AND ou.RecordTime = oop.TimeOff
> WHERE oop.groupname IS NULL
> ORDER BY 1, 2, 3, 5;
> ```
>
> ```
> groupname   | observer | ArrivalTime | TimeOn   | TimeOff 
> :---------- | :------- | :---------- | :------- | :-------
> Baobab      | DILA     | 07:55:52    | 08:58:45 | 10:50:42
> Baobab      | DILA     | 07:55:52    | null     | 10:51:13
> Baobab      | DILA     | 07:55:52    | null     | 10:56:36
> Baobab      | DILA     | 07:55:52    | 11:20:45 | 12:04:04
> Baobab      | DILA     | 07:55:52    | 10:59:58 | 12:04:04
> Make-e-plan | BANK     | 16:23:47    | 16:23:53 | 17:33:24
> Make-e-plan | BANK     | 16:23:47    | null     | 18:50:07
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=6381ee0351ddacbda433f2a580129e87)*

Comment: This seems like the near perfect solution. The only glitch in here is the duplicate of 12:04:04 on row 4 and 5, where we assume when there are two RecordON records in a row, the first Record On would miss the RecordOFF record, hence row 4 should be null (as can be seen in the expected results in my question). 
We are currently running MySQL 5.7, however the version 8.x approach seems much neater, I will fire up a virtual machine testing this soon!

Comment: I have added a solution that Jon and myself have been working on. It is maybe not as elegant, would you have any suggestions for this query? This is off course the 5.7 version that works as this would work in our enviroment up and till we would move to 8.0 when it becomes stable.

Comment: I don't see optimization capacity until you have window functions available. The solution you have is based on he one immediately above this comment I believe, so I'm pretty much out on ideas on this question. *Is it enough for "acceptance"?*

Answer (score 2):

Below I show 2 queries. The first is an "interim" step and I'm showing this so you may see the results of it. The second query adds logic that removes repeats of the `TimeOff` column and replaces those with NULLs.

Whilst you have provided sample data (thanks), you don't display the `expected result` based on that data. So to some extent I am guessing the details of what you really expect, hopefully it's close.

> ```
> create table `tbltest` (`id` int,`GroupName` varchar(40),`Observer` varchar(40),`ArrivalTime` time,`Behaviour` varchar(20),`RecordTime` time);
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO `tbltest` (`id`,`GroupName`,`Observer`,`ArrivalTime`,`Behaviour`,`RecordTime`)
> VALUES
>    (4865,'Make-e-plan','BANK','2017-08-26 16:23:47','RecON','16:23:53')
>  , (4878,'Make-e-plan','BANK','2017-08-26 16:23:47','RecOFF','17:33:24')
>  , (4890,'Make-e-plan','BANK','2017-08-26 16:23:47','RecOFF','18:50:07')
>  , (352,'Baobab','DILA','2017-08-16 07:55:52','RecON','08:58:45')
>  , (377,'Baobab','DILA','2017-08-16 07:55:52','RecOFF','10:50:42')
>  , (379,'Baobab','DILA','2017-08-16 07:55:52','RecOFF','10:51:13')
>  , (382,'Baobab','DILA','2017-08-16 07:55:52','RecOFF','10:56:36')
>  , (384,'Baobab','DILA','2017-08-16 07:55:52','RecON','10:59:58')
>  , (396,'Baobab','DILA','2017-08-16 07:55:52','RecON','11:20:45')
>  , (412,'Baobab','DILA','2017-08-16 07:55:52','RecOFF','12:04:04');
> ```

> ```
> select
>   groupname,observer,ArrivalTime, t1.RecordTime
> , (select min(t2.RecordTime)
>    from tbltest t2
>    where t2.GroupName = t1.GroupName and t2.Observer = t1.Observer
>    and t2.Behaviour = 'RecOFF' and t2.RecordTime > t1.RecordTime) min_t2_rt
> from tbltest t1
> where Behaviour = 'RecON'
> union all
> select
>   groupname,observer,ArrivalTime, t1.RecordTime
> , (select min(t2.RecordTime)
>    from tbltest t2
>    where t2.GroupName = t1.GroupName and t2.Observer = t1.Observer
>    and t2.Behaviour = 'RecON' and t2.RecordTime > t1.RecordTime) min_t2_rt
> from tbltest t1
> where Behaviour = 'RecOFF'
> order by 1,2,3,4
> ```
>
> ```
> groupname   | observer | ArrivalTime | RecordTime | min_t2_rt
> :---------- | :------- | :---------- | :--------- | :--------
> Baobab      | DILA     | 07:55:52    | 08:58:45   | 10:50:42 
> Baobab      | DILA     | 07:55:52    | 10:50:42   | 10:59:58 
> Baobab      | DILA     | 07:55:52    | 10:51:13   | 10:59:58 
> Baobab      | DILA     | 07:55:52    | 10:56:36   | 10:59:58 
> Baobab      | DILA     | 07:55:52    | 10:59:58   | 12:04:04 
> Baobab      | DILA     | 07:55:52    | 11:20:45   | 12:04:04 
> Baobab      | DILA     | 07:55:52    | 12:04:04   | null     
> Make-e-plan | BANK     | 16:23:47    | 16:23:53   | 17:33:24 
> Make-e-plan | BANK     | 16:23:47    | 17:33:24   | null     
> Make-e-plan | BANK     | 16:23:47    | 18:50:07   | null
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
>       groupname
>     , observer
>     , ArrivalTime
>     , TimeOn
>     , IF(@prev_value=TimeOff, NULL, TimeOff) TimeOff
>     , @prev_value := TimeOff x
> FROM (
>       SELECT
>             groupname
>           , observer
>           , ArrivalTime
>           , t1.RecordTime TimeOn
>           , (
>                   SELECT
>                         MIN(t2.RecordTime)
>                   FROM tbltest t2
>                   WHERE t2.GroupName = t1.GroupName
>                   AND t2.Observer = t1.Observer
>                   AND t2.Behaviour = 'RecOFF'
>                   AND t2.RecordTime > t1.RecordTime
>             )
>             TimeOff
>       FROM tbltest t1
>       WHERE Behaviour = 'RecON'
>       UNION ALL
>       SELECT
>             groupname
>           , observer
>           , ArrivalTime
>           , t1.RecordTime TimeOn
>           , (
>                   SELECT
>                         MIN(t2.RecordTime)
>                   FROM tbltest t2
>                   WHERE t2.GroupName = t1.GroupName
>                   AND t2.Observer = t1.Observer
>                   AND t2.Behaviour = 'RecON'
>                   AND t2.RecordTime > t1.RecordTime
>             )
>             TimeOff
>       FROM tbltest t1
>       WHERE Behaviour = 'RecOFF'
>       ORDER BY
>             groupname
>           , observer
>           , ArrivalTime
>           , TimeOn
>       ) d
> CROSS JOIN (SELECT @row_num :=1,  @prev_value :='00:00:00') vars
> ```
>
> ```
> groupname   | observer | ArrivalTime | TimeOn   | TimeOff  | x       
> :---------- | :------- | :---------- | :------- | :------- | :-------
> Baobab      | DILA     | 07:55:52    | 08:58:45 | 10:50:42 | 10:50:42
> Baobab      | DILA     | 07:55:52    | 10:50:42 | 10:59:58 | 10:59:58
> Baobab      | DILA     | 07:55:52    | 10:51:13 | null     | 10:59:58
> Baobab      | DILA     | 07:55:52    | 10:56:36 | null     | 10:59:58
> Baobab      | DILA     | 07:55:52    | 10:59:58 | 12:04:04 | 12:04:04
> Baobab      | DILA     | 07:55:52    | 11:20:45 | null     | 12:04:04
> Baobab      | DILA     | 07:55:52    | 12:04:04 | null     | null    
> Make-e-plan | BANK     | 16:23:47    | 16:23:53 | 17:33:24 | 17:33:24
> Make-e-plan | BANK     | 16:23:47    | 17:33:24 | null     | null    
> Make-e-plan | BANK     | 16:23:47    | 18:50:07 | null     | null
> ```

*dbfiddle (mariadb_10.2) [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=00a22333555ae5f5ab3b69c84ecfcbbd)*

By the way, I didn't get your query to work "as is", so I wasn't able to compare results.

### ----

Oh, and when MySQL v8.x does hit the streets, and it supports window functions such as `LAG() OVER` and `LEAD() OVER` then this query will be ever so much easier to write. If you happen to be using MariaDB or pre-release MySQL 8.x you should try using those window functions. The dbfiddle I used does support those functions if you want to "try it"

Comment: Thanks for this input, it seems already a bit better in setup compared to my query, however not the desired outcome (which I should have specified on the example data) See the bottom of my post, where I show the expected outcome of example data. In your outcome the times are repeated between timeOff (record 1) and timeOn (record 2), this is also one issue I have. Do you have any idea how to get past this?